# jQuery AJAX on select box

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax on a select box and change html elements with matching id's on event of change in select box. I have a code like below but it does not seem to work and rather generates 'Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined'

Below is the code that I am using. Is there something wrong with this?

```
$('#PolicyCategory').live('change',function(){
    var policy = $('#PolicyCategory').val();
    var form_data = {
        category_id: policy,
        ajax: '1'       
    };

    console.log();
    alert(data.conn);

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://coverbuddy.favstay.com/users/category_ajax",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes up from

```
alert(data.conn);
```

Where you don't have defined variable `data` as far as we can see from your code.
Remove this line or define the variable before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the variable `data` is not defined in your script and is caused here:

```
 alert(data.conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to to use data where it is not defined: `alert(data.conn);`, which naturally gives you the error

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to write the " alert(data.conn);" with in the success function..

```
$('#PolicyCategory').live('change',function(){
    var policy = $('#PolicyCategory').val();
    var form_data = {
        category_id: policy,
        ajax: '1'       
    };
    console.log();


    $.ajax({
        url: "http://coverbuddy.favstay.com/users/category_ajax",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data : form_data,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            alert(data.conn);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

that's  because of the `alert(data.conn);`

remove it and it will work